# populate comboBox with both Name and Value,

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I'm have a `combobox` listing some single byte cmds that can be sent to some custom hardware I've developed.  With the C# code below, users can currently select commands from the `cbCANcmd` by name only.  I also found ways to display the values only, but prefer to display both name and number.

1. How can I display both hex value & `cmd` in the cb dropdown? e.g. `0d - CommsSoftReset`
2. And still able to type in `un-enumerated` values, like `05`, for unlisted commands?
3. Can I hide more dangerous items easily(i.e. `09-WipeAllFlash`), but still numerically enter them as per #2 above?

Note: The enum is from a straight C language .h file, and the header is changing more times daily than the c# app.  For this reason, I'm hoping to avoid adding `[Description()]` for each value, or dramatically change the formatting, since it will have to be copied and redone many times as we continue development)

P.S. I normally write only in simple C, for the 8bit micro receiving these commands..As this is my first test app in c#, please be gentle :)

```
enum COMMS_MESSAGE_ID_t : byte  
{  
    CommsRAMRead = 0x00,
    CommsRAMWrite = 0x01,
    CommsCommitRAMbufferToFlash = 0x02,                 

    CommsWipeAllFlash = 0x0c,
    CommsSoftReset = 0x0d,

    CommsGetVersion = 0xff
}

private void SendTab_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //need to populate the pulldowns with the available commands
    cbCANcmd.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(COMMS_MESSAGE_ID_t)); 
}

private void SendDownlinkCmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // send the command selected in the send tab's combobox
    byte CANcmd = (byte)(COMMS_MESSAGE_ID_t)cbCANcmd.SelectedValue;//first byte           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a WinForms app, here is a possible solution for #1. If this works, we can move on from there.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var val in Enum.GetNames(typeof(COMMS_MESSAGE_ID_t)))
        {
            cbCANcmd.Items.Add(new CommsMessage(val));
        }
    }

}

public class CommsMessage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public COMMS_MESSAGE_ID_t Message { get; set; }

    public CommsMessage(string msgName)
    {
        Name = msgName;
        Message = (COMMS_MESSAGE_ID_t)Enum.Parse(typeof (COMMS_MESSAGE_ID_t), msgName);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0:x} - {1}", Message, Name);
    }
}
```

Then, any time you get the value of the ComboBox.SelectedItem, you can do something like:

```
COMMS_MESSAGE_ID_t msg = (cbCANcmd.SelectedItem as CommsMessage).Message;
```

I've left out lots of exception handling that you should probably do, but I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This works. Thank you!  I did have to move the code in 'public partial Form1Load' to my 'private Form1Load', but not sure why.  Got me started though, and will upvote when my rep allows.

Comment: Cool! Glad it worked for you! If you want to handle #2 (values that aren't in the enum), just add a constructor to CommsMessage that accepts a byte (and optionally a string, for a name). For #3, the easiest way to do it is to keep a list of "dangerous" commands and filter them out when you add items to the ComboBox. Personally, I would manage these "dangerous commands" from the app.config or Settings, so you can add or remove them without needing to recompile.